# Reference other sheets in Google Sheets using file name?

Tags: google-sheets, import

I have a set of Google Sheets workbooks in a Google Drive folder that reference each other. One of the source workbooks contains data that is externally updated daily which then replaces the same workbook from the day before (Data Sheet). It is referenced in the other sheets using the IMPORTRANGE function, but whenever the source file is updated, the url/key changes. Is there any way to reference the Data Sheet by file name instead of url so that I don't have to change the url references in all the other sheets each time?

If there is no other way, I suppose I could have the relevant sheets manually transferred into the existing Data Sheet daily but if it's at all possible, referencing by file name would be ideal! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The question is off-topic in [su]. The starndard How to ask guides requires users to first search the site throhougly. Questions about Google Sheets might be on-topic in [webapps.se] and [so], so the best is that you search both sites. Once you have done this, try to solve the problem by yourself, if you still need help, share what they have tried, what you found and why it didn't  meet their needs. In the this case, if you really search thoroughly you will learn that you will need to use Google Apps Script, an add-on, another app or the Sheets API and the Google Drive API.

Comment: Apologies for this misstep. I admit to having a very limited understanding on the subject, hence my posting on the wrong forum. I did attempt to search on several other forum sites but came up empty, again perhaps due to limitations on my part to phrase searches accurately and clearly. Thank you for the nudge in the right direction.